# Hosting WCF ON IIS7

Tags: wcf, iis-7

Here is my config file of my W CF web service:

```
<services>
  <service behavior Configuration="METADATASERVICEEXTENSION" name="namespace.MYwebServiceclass">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="" binding="ws2007HttpBinding"
      binding Configuration="xxx" name="xxx" contract="IMyWebService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="" />
        <certificateReference yyyyyy="xxxxxx" find Value=""
          ISCHAINincluded="false" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" binding Configuration=""
      name="Metadata Exchange" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
```

I am getting the following error : Could not find a base address that matches scheme HTTP for the endpoint with binding WS2007HttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [HTTPS]. 
- I have this service configured to HTTPS : 443, Any changes to my web config???

Here is my binding section:

```
<bindings>
  <ws2007HttpBinding>
    <binding name="xxxxx">
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
        <message clientCredentialType="None" negotiateServiceCredential="false"
          establishSecurityContext="false" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </ws2007HttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: Your binding configuration is missing.

Comment: Can you show the binding section for your binding?

Comment: That's your services section - we'd like to see your bindings section as well, as the problem could be there.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! This way, even code and XML shows up just fine!

Comment: HTTPS typically means that you have to define a transport-level security scheme

Comment: Is your service supposed to run over SSL (https)?

Comment: yes it is supposed to run only on SSL HTTPS

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the following in the security element for mode:

```
<security mode="transport">
```